# Missing number in a 5x5 table

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I'm trying to find a solution for the following puzzle. A friend sent it to me and I know that he didn't create it and that's about it for the original source; I tried to find it on the net but I couldn't make it.

Here it goes:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 9 | 6 | 12 | 3 |
| 7 | 14 | 11 | 7 | 21 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 9 |
| 13 | 9 | 11 | 16 | ? |

I tried with sums, differences, products, ratios, and a difference table, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: How do you know it's about patterns and calculations? Why not cipher for instance?

Comment: I assumed it was because I exchange only puzzles of this kind with my friend. But you're right, I can't rule out your hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is 11, I forgot to try linear combinations on the columns.

For example, the first element of the fifth row (a<sub>5,1</sub> = 13) comes up as a result of the following operation:

> a<sub>5,1</sub> = (a<sub>1,1</sub> + a<sub>2,1</sub>) - (a<sub>3,1</sub> + a<sub>4,1</sub>)

So the answer is: (3+21) - (4+9) = 11